# What's the advantage of running OpenCL code on aCPU?

Tags: c, performance, opencl, intel, processor

I am learning OpenCL programming and am noticing something weird.

Namely, when I list all OpenCL enabled devices on my machine (Macbook Pro), I get the following list:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4850HQ CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Iris Pro
- GeForce GT 750M

The first is my CPU, the second is the onboard graphics solution by Intel and the third is my dedicated graphics card.

Research shows that Intel has made their hardware OpenCL compatible so that I can tap into the power of the onboard graphics unit. That would be the Iris Pro.

With that in mind, what is the purpose of the CPU being OpenCL compatible? Is it merely for convenience so that kernels can be run on a CPU as backup should no other cards be found or is there any kind of speed advantage when running code as OpenCL kernels instead of regular (C, well threaded) programs on top of a CPU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/Writing_Optimal_OpenCL_28tm_29_Code_with_Intel_28R_29_OpenCL_SDK.pdf for basic info.

Basically the Intel OpenCL compiler performs horizontal autovectorization for certain types of kernels. That means with SSE4 you get 8 threads running in parallel in a single core in similar fashion as Nvidia GPU runs 32 threads in a single 32 wide simd unit.

There are 2 major benefits on this approach: What happens if in 2 years they increase the SSE vector width to 16? Then you will instantly get autovectorization for 16 threads when you run on that CPU. No need to recompile your code. The second benefit is that it's far easier to write an OpenCL kernel that autovectorizes easily compared to writing it in ASM or C and getting your compiler to produce efficient code.

Comment: Auto-vectorization is overrated. If you want performance for a particular device (which is why you use OpenCL) you must think about how to implement SIMD best on that device. For example if you write a matrix multiplication kernel which relies on auto-vectorization for SIMD it won't get anywhere close to peak performance across SSE, AVX, FMA, and AVX512. You have to write a kernel for each device and then hope that the device driver implements SIMD the way you want.

Comment: Vectorized code (what OpenCL is) is much superior to standard CPU domain decomposition as it explicitely allows for vectorization. OpenCL code automatically is vectorized on the CPU. On an Intel Coffee-Lake CPU with 256-bit SSE4.2/AVX2 registers, OpenCL really runs close to 8x faster out of the box than the same code in C++, where autovectorization in many cases fails.

Answer (score 4):

I have considered this for a while. You can get most of the advantages of OpenCL for the CPU without using OpenCL and without too much difficulty in C++. To do this you need:

1. Something for multi-threading - I use OpenMP for this
2. A SIMD library - I use Agner Fog's [Vector Library Class (VCL)](http://agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) for this which covers SSE2-AVX512.
3. A SIMD math library. Once again I use Anger Fog's VCL for this.
4. A CPU dispatcher. Agner Fog's VCL has an example to do this.

Using the CPU dispatcher you determine what hardware is available and choose the best code path based on the hardware. This provides one of the advantages of OpenCL.

This gives you most of the advantages of OpenCL on the CPU without all its disadvantages. You never have to worry that a vendor stops supporting a driver. Nvidia has only a minimal amount of support for OpenCL - including several year old bugs it will likely never fix (which I wasted too much time on). Intel only has Iris Pro OpenCL drivers for Windows. Your kernels using my suggested method can use all C++ features, including templates, instead of OpenCL's restricted and extended version of C (though I do like the extensions).  You can be sure your code does what you want this way and are not at the whim of some device driver.

The one disadvantage with my suggested method is that you can't just install a new driver and have it optimize for new hardware. However, the VCL already supports AVX512 so it's already built for hardware that is not out yet and won't be superseded for several years. And in any case to get the most use of your hardware you will almost certainly have to rewrite your kernel in OpenCL for that hardware - a new driver can only help so much.

More info on the SIMD math library. You could use Intel's expensive closed source SVML for this (which is what the Intel OpenCL drivers uses if you search of svml after you install the Intel OpenCL drivers - don't confuse the SDK with the drivers). Or you could use AMD's free but closed source LIBM. However,neither of these work well on the competitors processor. Agner Fog's VCL works well on both processors, is open source, and free.

Comment: Note that VLC uses GPL as license, so it's usable only for open source code.

Comment: @zymzam, Agner says "Commercial licenses are available on request." BTW, I had the acronym wrong. It's VCL.

Answer (score 4):

As OpenCL implementations mature, it's possible to achieve good levels of performance portability for your kernels across a wide range of devices. Some recent work in my research group shows that, in some cases, OpenCL codes achieve a similar fraction of hardware peak performance on the CPU and the GPU. On the CPU, the OpenCL kernels were being very effectively auto-vectorised by Intel's OpenCL CPU implementation. On the GPU, efficient code was being generated for HPC and desktop devices from Nvidia (who's OpenCL still works surprisingly well) and AMD.

If you want to develop your OpenCL code anyway in order to exploit the GPU, then you're often getting a fast multi-core+SIMD version "for free" by running the same code on the CPU.

For two recent papers from my group detailing the performance portability results we've achieved across four different real applications with OpenCL, see:

"On the performance portability of structured grid codes on many-core computer architectures", S.N. McIntosh-Smith, M. Boulton, D. Curran and J.R. Price. ISC, Leipzig, June 2014. DOI: 10.1007/978-3-319-07518-1_4

"High Performance in silico Virtual Drug Screening on Many-Core Processors", S. McIntosh-Smith, J. Price, R.B. Sessions, A.A. Ibarra, IJHPCA 2014. DOI: 10.1177/1094342014528252